# Linear transforms and their corresponding invertible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ be a basis for $\mathscr{P_3}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $(1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4)$ be a basis for $\mathscr{P_4}(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose $R \in \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P_4}(\mathbb{R}),\mathscr{P_3}(\mathbb{R}))$, $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
is $\mathscr{M}(R)$ and $p=x^4 +2x^3-x$. Find $(\mathscr{M}^{-1}(A))p$. Note $(\mathscr{M}^{-1}(A)) \neq (\mathscr{M}(A))^{-1}$

Comment: What is $\mathscr{M}(R)$?

Comment: This is matrix representation of the linear map $R \in \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P}_4(\mathbb{R})),\mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P}_3(\mathbb{R}))$. Another note, $ A=\mathscr{M}(R)$.

Comment: And what is $\mathscr{M}(A)$ and $\mathscr{M}^{-1}(A)$? A general remark: If you ask questions in this forum, it is often a good idea to explain the notation you are using. (Of course, this is not necessary if you are using standard notation. But this is probably not the case in your question.)

Comment: What is $\mathscr{M}(A)$?

Comment: $M^{_1}(A)$ is the inverse of R represented by a matrix